# Draw a curly bracket over two lines in a matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I would like to draw a curly bracket for two lines of the legend, like so:

[image: curly bracket indicates a shared property for two legend entries]

I am able to create everything with pyplot except for the curly bracket using

```
plt.plot([],[],"ro",label="a")
plt.plot([],[],"bo",label="b")
plt.legend(frameon=False,loc="upper left")
plt.annotate("some property",
            xy=(0.31, 0.7), xycoords='figure fraction',
            xytext=(0.31,  0.79), textcoords='figure fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",lw=0
                       )
            )
 plt.plot()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder how you manage to create an annotation showing `"some property"` but fail to create one showing `"}"`.

Comment: Me too. That's why I came here. Like I said above: Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: Ok, I get it now... thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by ImportanceOfBeingErnest I realized the obvious solution of simply adding another annotation:

```
plt.annotate(r"$\}$",fontsize=24,
            xy=(0.27, 0.77), xycoords='figure fraction'
            )
```